# How do I merge contacts based on phone numbers?

Tags: contacts

I have been using 2 SIM cards in 2 separate phones and until recently I bought the Alcatel OT-918N Glory, a dual SIM Android phone.

Since I had 2 phones before, I am expecting to have duplicated contact numbers. I will be importing numbers from my 2 SIM cards and I need to know the best way to handle duplicate numbers in Android.

Is there a way to merge contact numbers based on the phone numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can pull both sets of contacts into the Google Contacts app on the phone, and let them sync with Google, you *might* then be able to merge duplicates via the web-based contacts page: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts  Click the "More" button, then choose "Find and Merge duplicates".

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a non-google option.