# How can I merge duplicated contacts that are different only in one letter?

Tags: contacts

I use "Contact Remover Plus" to merge duplicated contacts. But I want also merge contacts that their names are different just in a letter.

How can I merge these duplicated contacts? I am looking for a automatic solution.

Comment: @RyanConrad Google Contact web app do not merge contacts that are different in name!

Comment: no, but it is still the easiest to edit them if needed. And, for the record, if the contacts have things like the same email (and maybe even phone number) it can merge them. I have had it merge people that I did not want merged because the email addresses were the same.

Comment: What Ryan said answers the question. Not yours as that's off-topic, but it's your best choice. Also, please try to be more civil and less demanding.

Comment: "Is there an app for X?" questions are [off-topic on Android
Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq). That's why I have edited your question to ask for a solution instead of an app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge contacts based on phone numbers?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21241/how-do-i-merge-contacts-based-on-phone-numbers)

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate, it may produces the same answers but the constraints are different.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/) is your best option. It will merge contacts with different names if things like their email addresses are the same. Also, if for some reason, it doesn't detect the contacts that should be merged, you can select multiple contacts manually and click on `Merge Contacts` from the more actions menu.

Comment: I definitely second Ryan. It's best to use the web tool for this task (it has 'revert' too).

Answer (score 2):

Use latest version of MyPhoneExplorer (www.fjsoft.at). It is compatible with nearly any android phone. connect your phone with Bluetooth or USB to PC. Sync your contacts with the software, then you are able to easily merge your contacts by selecting some of them and right-click -> Merge Contacts.

Note, this requires installation of a client on your Windows desktop (no Mac or Linux available)